# Typhoon in December of 1864 in Japan?

Tags: tropical-cyclone

In "20,000 Leagues Under the Sea" by Jules Verne there is a reference to a "tempest" that destroyed Yeddo (Tokyo) in Japan:

> They are they which, in the tempest of December 23, 1864, after
>   destroying the town of Yeddo, in Japan, broke the same day on the
>   shores of America.

Was this a real event or just fiction?